# Wolfram kernel on Nteract?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[Nteract](https://nteract.io/kernels) is a nice desktop client for jupyter kernels:

[image]

Now that we have the Jupyter Client for Wolfram, I'm wondering how Nteract could be connected to the free Wolfram engine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 20190705**

Given the popularity of this question, it might be good to know why the OP (and possibly many others) didn't get WL running under Jupyter. So I provide the recipe below (all below tested under macOS):

#### 1. Inspect the installed kernels:

By running

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

One would see:

```
python3                /Users/sunt05/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
wlengine               /Users/sunt05/Library/Jupyter/kernels/wlengine
wolframlanguage12      /Users/sunt05/Library/Jupyter/kernels/wolframlanguage12
```

So we know the kernels are correctly installed (here I have both Mathematica and WLE).

#### 2. Explore the kernel spec file:

By navigating into one of the above folders, one may see the magic happens right in the `kernel.json` file.

The one below is for WL:

```
{
    "argv":[
        "/Applications/Wolfram Engine.app/Contents/Resources/Wolfram Player.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel",
        "-script",
        "\/Users\/sunt05\/Downloads\/WolframLanguageForJupyter-master\/WolframLanguageForJupyter\/Resources\/KernelForWolframLanguageForJupyter.wl",
        "{connection_file}",
        "ScriptInstall"
    ],
    "display_name":"Wolfram Language 12 WL",
    "language":"Wolfram Language"
}
```

So if the kernel spec is not properly installed, one can also manually create a such kernel json file and put the info of WLE in.

Hope this might be helpful.

---

Simply install the kernel for the Jupyter environment following the official guide: https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter

then WL would be there (tested on macOS with Anaconda Python 3.7.3):

[image]

A noting caveat is that the auto-completion is missing.

Environment info:

```
conda version : 4.6.14
conda-build version : 3.17.8
python version : 3.7.3.final.0
```

Comment: My kernel.json was pointing to `[...Mathematica 12.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/WolframKernel",
  "-script", ... ]`... could that be a problem?

Comment: @M.R. Yes, that’s what I guess you might have. So you can manually create another kernel file pointing to WLE to resolve this issue.

Comment: Yea I just had to do this: `jupyter kernelspec uninstall wolframlanguage-12.0.0`, now working, thanks :)

Comment: Great to know this has been resolved :)

Comment: Unfortunately none of the useful parts of mathematica frontend are available

Comment: Is there any way to get autocompletion or Manipulate to work?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the notebook here will help. Not sure, since I am not familiar with Nteract. https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1717637